# need captcha plugin for custom form in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, captcha

I need `Captcha plugin` for **WordPress**. There are more Plugin. But I need to call Captcha, where I need. Not Only Login form, Comment form.

`EX:` I created one form. I need to Set Captcha for that form.

Is there any Idea or Option? I didn't ask `recommendation`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one might work for you.  It was initially intended for CF7 but you can use it on your custom form as well.  The first page describes how to auth and it is fairly simple text.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/really-simple-captcha/

Although, personally I use this http://www.phpcaptcha.org/ where for me it was easier to implement on my custom forms.  You can customize the image display so that it can show whatever you want it to show.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about other captcha plugins.

But you can use "Gravity Forms" for wordpress which will surely satisfy your need with some extra cookies like great UI of the forms and other support plugins.

But if you do not want to change ur pre-defined form then you can use the below links for your reference.

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/wordpress

and

https://www.keycaptcha.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are several security captcha solutions you can use but using the [Really Simple Captcha plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-captcha/) with it's API/functions is the quickest solution.

See [How to use Really Simple Captcha plugin with your plugin or theme](http://www.lost-in-code.com/platforms/wordpress/wordpress-plugins/wordpress-using-really-simple-captcha/).

Since many WordPress plugins already integrate with Really Simple Captcha plugin, chances are that you may have it installed already or that you will find it useful in the future if you do install it.